# What does "error: invalid types 'float [10001][float]' for array subscript" mean?

Tags: c++

I am trying to put some real numbers in a vector. Please help me because I don't know what the problem is.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
float i, n, v[10001];
int k;
int main()
{
    cin >> n;
    for(i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        cin >> v[i];
    for(i = 2; i <= n - 1; i++)
        if(v[i] >= v[1] && v[i] <= v[n])
            k++;
    cout << k;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `n` is a `float`. Array indices are `unsigned integers`, so using a `float` is not valid. You can probably just make `n` an `int` instead.

Comment: Sidenote: Comparisons with floating point numbers can get a bit dicey. See [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) for a discussion on the topic.

Comment: @user4581301 Equality comparisons can, yes. `<=` and `>=` decidedly less so in most cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot address an array with a float:

```
cin>>v[i];
```

with

```
float i;
```

`i` being a floating point number, it wouldn't point to an exact spot in the array. You need:

```
 int i,n;
 float v[10001];
```

Comment: Also, keep in mind that the first element in the array is `v[0]`, not `v[1]`.